# How to extract the survival rate from a ctree in R?

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis, party

[image: The Curve]

```
K <- HF %>% 
  filter(serum_creatinine <= 1.8, ejection_fraction > 25, age > 79)

pred_k <- ctree(Surv(time, DEATH_EVENT) ~ ., data = K)
```

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Heart+failure+clinical+records

I'm wanting to get the survival rate at t=150. This is my first ever Kaplan Meier model. Just don't know how to extract it.

Using summary(pred_k) doesn't return calculations for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the `summary()` method to the Kaplan-Meier estimates you need to extract the `survfit` object first. You can do so either by re-fitting `survfit()` to all of the terminal nodes of the tree simultaneously. Or, alternatively, by using `predict()` to obtain the fitted Kaplan-Meier curve for every individual observation.

To make the example easily reproducible, let's consider the following illustration from `?ctree` in `partykit`:

```
library("partykit")
library("survival")
data("GBSG2", package = "TH.data")
ct <- ctree(Surv(time, cens) ~ ., data = GBSG2)
plot(ct)
```

[image: plot of ctree survival tree on GBSG2 data]

Now we can extract the IDs of the terminal nodes (3, 4, 6, 7) for every observation in the learning data by:

```
nd <- factor(predict(ct, type = "node"))
```

And then we can build the corresponding four-group `survfit` object for the entire learning data and work with it "as usual" in `survival`.

```
sf <- survfit(Surv(time, cens) ~ nd, data = GBSG2)
summary(sf, time = 1500)
## Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, cens) ~ nd, data = GBSG2)
## 
##                 nd=3 
##         time       n.risk      n.event     survival      std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI 
##     1.50e+03     8.30e+01     7.70e+01     6.31e-01     3.45e-02     5.67e-01     7.03e-01 
## 
##                 nd=4 
##         time       n.risk      n.event     survival      std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI 
##     1.50e+03     6.40e+01     2.30e+01     7.89e-01     3.96e-02     7.15e-01     8.71e-01 
## 
##                 nd=6 
##         time       n.risk      n.event     survival      std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI 
##     1.50e+03     2.00e+01     9.80e+01     2.29e-01     4.01e-02     1.62e-01     3.22e-01 
## 
##                 nd=7 
##         time       n.risk      n.event     survival      std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI 
##     1.50e+03     4.70e+01     6.80e+01     5.19e-01     4.38e-02     4.40e-01     6.13e-01 
plot(sf, col = 1:4)
```

[image: plot of survival curves from four-group survfit on GBSG2 data]

Alternatively, you can extract the `survfit` for an individual observation as well, here we extract the object for the first observation in the learning data:

```
sf1 <- predict(ct, type = "prob")[[1]]
summary(sf1, time = 1500)
## Call: survfit(formula = y ~ 1, weights = w, subset = w > 0)
## 
##  time n.risk n.event survival std.err lower 95% CI upper 95% CI
##  1500     83      77    0.631  0.0345        0.567        0.703
plot(sf1)
```

[image: plot of the predicted survival curve for the first observation in the GBSG2 data]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you. Could you explain the reasons behind having different curves from nodes on the same plot? Though it's nice, I'm a bit confused about the reasoning for it since the curves are made from different subsets of the larger data.

Comment: It's easier to compare the survival curves from different groups, when they are in the same panel - as opposed to different panels. For example in the tree diagram you can sort of see that the survival curve in Node 3 is below that of Node 4 but it's hard to gauge by how much. In the survfit plot with all four curves in the same panel it's easier to compare the black and red curve (pertaining to Node 3 and 4).

Comment: Your example has nodes with large number of observations for each. Do you know if this is still useful when number of observations range from small (10-20 obs.) to large?

Comment: The precision of the estimates in the different nodes/groups will then be very different. 10 observations sounds very small to me, not sure if I would use such a Kaplan-Meier curve. But I'm no survival expert.